# May Have put Supreme gas in car instead of regular

Tags: chevrolet, fuel-system, sonic

I just filled up my 2014 Chevy Sonic LT at the gas station. I had a faulty gas pump. I am not sure, but the pump may have put supreme fuel into the gas tank instead of regular. Would I feel a difference in driving the car, and could it harm the engine?